# getting error while i use constructor with inharitance

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

Here's my code. It gives me an error! Does anyone know why this is?
It has something to do with constructors and inheritance, I think. Please help me to the best of your abilities,

Yours truly, the programmer.

```
    class Person{
    int age;
    String name;
    Person(int age, String name){
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;
    }
    
}
class Student extends Person{
    
    String school;
    
}
class Employee extends Person{
    
    }
    int salary;
}
```

Comment: Either add a no-arg constructor to the parent, or have each child invoke the parent's two-arg constructor from their constructor.

Comment: @mre is right. You see, each property initialized in the parent constructor also exists in the child classes and so the child classes need a matching constructor so that all data is instantialized properly.

Comment: the first solution that @mre said is worked but i did not understand the second "have each child...". Could you please give me an example as a written code?

Comment: @muhammedikbalaktaş example provided in the answer

Comment: thank you soo much for all your help. I'm grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Example of inherited constructor for `Student`:

```
public class Student {
    String school;

    public Student(int age, String name, String school) {
        super(age, name);     // call parent class constructor
        this.school = school;
    }
}
```

Similar change has to be implemented in `Employee` class - I'll leave it as an exercise.